# Discord bot defined command not found

Tags: python, discord.py

I coded a Discord economy bot in python using discord.py. I set the command prefix as 'kash ' using command_prefix = 'kash '. But when I use one of the commands that I defined AND coded earlier, it returned with a traceback saying that the command is not defined. I've tried changing the prefix and command names, but it doesn't work. Here is the complete traceback:

```
Ignoring exception in command None: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "stock" is not found
```

Here is the code until the stock function:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import yfinance as yf

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'kash ')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.command
async def stock():
    await message.channel.send('Please type: \n`$stock list` for list of stocks \n`$stock price` for a price of a specific stock \n`$buy` to buy a stock \n`$sell` to sell a stock')
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: It has to be `@client.command()`. Mostly it also takes an argument like `ctx` so it would be `async def stock(ctx)` and then you can just use `ctx.send("YourMessage")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have to call `client.command`

```py
@client.command()
async def stock(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Please type: \n`$stock list` for list of stocks \n`$stock price` for a price of a specific stock \n`$buy` to buy a stock \n`$sell` to sell a stock')
```

PS: Commands always take `ctx` as the first argument, it's the [`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context)